# Removing rows until a metric point is reached and extracting the minimum value

Tags: python, pandas

I'am classifying some text using a Machine learning model. Essentially I am fitting 80% of the data to the model and predicting the remaining 20%. On top of this, for each classification, I am outputting a confidence level as given by the ML model and and a `check` variable, which is set to `TRUE` if the prediction is correct and `FALSE` otherwise.

The data frame output I get from the process above looks like this:

```
+----------------------+
|  confidence   Check  |
+----------------------+
|  1            TRUE   |
|  0.72         TRUE   |
|  0.68         TRUE   |
|  1            TRUE   |
|  0.150287157  FALSE  |
|  1            TRUE   |
|  0.7          TRUE   |
|  0.68         TRUE   |
|  1            TRUE   |
|  0.903333333  FALSE  |
+----------------------+
```

I would like to know what the minimum confidence level is that approximates 95% accuracy the closest in the data set. E.g, If I remove enough rows with `FALSE` Values, starting with the rows which have the lowest confidence levels and are `FALSE`, what is the minimum confidence level in the data set which is reached?

I compute accuracy as the number of rows which are `TRUE` divided by the the total number of rows in the data frame.

How can I do this?

Comment: How do you calculate the minimum level of confidence?

Comment: I don't calculate it. I just retrieve it from the resulting data frame. So its, essentially, the minimum value of the dataframe that produces 95% accurancy. I currently have a visual build in PowerBI to do this, but I need it in Python as its part of a bigger process I am automating.

Comment: @smici, Perhaps I did not explained it correctly, but the answer is not to just reorder the dataframe, its not that simple. I will try to rephrase my question better and the output I want to get. I any case, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Pythonista: I provided the solution first. See my third and final hint. After you find the number of the row n, then you can pick your cutoff confidence threshold as any number between `df.iloc[n-1].confidence` ... `df.iloc[n].confidence`

Comment: @smci, thank you very much. But you are computing the mean value of the confidence? I am looking for the minimum confidence which approximates 95% accuracy by removing FALSES from the dataset. accuracy is computes as total rows TRUE divided by total amount of rows

Comment: No, I've been telling you I'm computing exactly what you're asking for: the confidence as total rows TRUE divided by total amount of rows (i.e. first filter/remove rows with `iloc[n:]`, then `df.iloc[n:].Check.mean()`. The code works and was working 5 hours ago. Run it first before you tell me it's wrong.

Comment: @smci thanks for your answer! I've ran your code multiple times and it does what I want indeed. I just got confused with the .mean(), but I now noticed its the same as counting true and dividing my the total amount of rows. I will mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

1. read your dataframe in (code below), treating `Check` column as int (rather than boolean), and sort in order of increasing `confidence`.
2. now look at the values as you sweep your confidence threshold over rows:
   `[ round(df.iloc[n:].Check.mean(), 3) for n in range(len(df.index))]` which gives `[0.8, 0.889, 0.875, 0.857, 0.833, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]`
3. after you find the number of the cutoff row `n`, then `df.iloc[n].confidence` gives you a cutoff confidence value which gives >= 0.95 accuracy. Hence **you can pick your cutoff confidence threshold as any number between `df.iloc[n-1].confidence`  ... `df.iloc[n].confidence`**

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

dat = """confidence   Check
1            TRUE
0.72         TRUE
0.68         TRUE
1            TRUE
0.150287157  FALSE
1            TRUE
0.7          TRUE
0.68         TRUE
1            TRUE
0.903333333  FALSE"""

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(dat), header=0, delim_whitespace=True, dtype={'confidence':'float', 'Check':'int'})
df.sort_values(by='confidence', inplace=True)

df

   confidence  Check
4    0.150287      0
2    0.680000      1
7    0.680000      1
6    0.700000      1
1    0.720000      1
9    0.903333      0
0    1.000000      1
3    1.000000      1
5    1.000000      1
8    1.000000      1

# Sweep over the df, finding the cutoff row which gives us 0.95 confidence...
for n in range(len(df.index)):
    if df.iloc[n:].Check.mean() >= 0.95:
        break

# ...then find the range for the cutoff confidence level
print("Cutoff confidence level is between:", df.iloc[n-1].confidence, df.iloc[n].confidence)

# Cutoff confidence level is between: 0.903333333 1.0
```

Comment: smci, thanks for your answer! However, this is exactly where I am stuck at the moment. So I've sorted the values, but now I want to remove "0" (as in your example) until I reach a 95% accuracy level ( e.g. 1/(1+0) ) and check what the minimum confidence level is. BTW, It was not me who down voted your answer.

Comment: Second hint:  look at `[ round(df.iloc[n:].Check.mean(), 3) for n in range(len(df.index))]` as you sweep `n`, which gives `[0.8, 0.889, 0.875, 0.857, 0.833, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]`

Comment: Third hint: after you find the number of the row n, then `df.iloc[n].confidence` gives you a cutoff confidence value which gives >= 0.95 accuracy. Hence you can pick your cutoff confidence threshold as any number between `df.iloc[n-1].confidence`  ... `df.iloc[n].confidence`

Comment: Fourth hint: if you want to exclude rows with df.Check==False then increasing values of confidence, then change it to `df.sort_values(by=['Check','confidence'], ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import math
accuracy=0.95
#df=df.replace('TRUE',True).replace('FALSE',False) 

#contains the number of True an the number of False
total_True=df['Check'][df['Check']].sum()
total_false=len(df)-total_True
#Calculate the num of false max to this precision and total_true
n_false_max=math.floor(total_True/(accuracy)-total_True)

#Order the DataFrame to drop the number of False excluding
df_sorted=df.sort_values(['Check','confidence']).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_sorted)
#Select the min level of confident
if n_false_max==0:
        print('95% accuracy is not possible')
        accuracy_remove1=total_True/(total_True+1)
        print('Accuracy with remove all False except one: ',accuracy_remove1*100)


        if (1-precision)<(precision-accuracy_remove1):
            nearest_accuracy=100
            print('nearest Accuracy 100%')
        else:
            nearest_accuracy=accuracy_remove1*100
            print('Nearest Acuracy: ',nearest_accuracy )
            min_level_of_confident=df_sorted.iloc[(total_false-1):].iloc[0].confidence
            print('Min Confident level associated:',min_level_of_confident)


elif total_false==0:
    print('for every level of trust is over 95%')
else:
    min_level_of_confident=df_sorted.iloc[(total_false-n_false_max):].iloc[0].confidence
    print(min_level_of_confident)
```

**Output**

```
   confidence  Check
0    0.150287  False
1    0.903333  False
2    0.680000   True
3    0.680000   True
4    0.700000   True
5    0.720000   True
6    1.000000   True
7    1.000000   True
8    1.000000   True
9    1.000000   True
95% accuracy is not possible
Accuracy with remove all False except one:  88.88888888888889
nearest Accuracy 100%
```

Comment: this is awesome! the only thing is that its a hard coded 95% accuracy, would it be possible to get an approximation? If I would get 0.9545 or 0.9432 is also fine, I just need the minimum confidence level that gets me the closest to 95% accuracy.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly

Comment: My apologies for not specifying it clearly, but I need to know what the minimum confidence level is that approximates 0.95 accuracy level by removing FALSES which have lowest confidence until that minimum confidence level is reached. So having "95% accuracy is not possible" is not a possibility.

Comment: in the case of the example, it is only possible to reach such a level of precision if all False ones are eliminated. That's why resilvi with a print. Now I have added the precision obtained by eliminating all false ones except one and the level of confidence associated

Comment: @ansev, Its almost there, however, I need the confidence level which approximates 0.95 accuracy the most, even if its at at 0.85 accuracy. So the accuracy level is actually variable approximating 0.95 accuracy the most

Comment: You cannot get accuracy levels between 88% and 95% (removing False) in this example... the only way is to increase the number of True

Comment: Do you want I add True values?

Comment: that is to say if it eliminates all the FALSE the result is 100% accuracy. If the eliminated all but 1 the accuracy is 88%. Therefore the only way to get closer to 95% is to add True. I think he answered more than clearly his question

Comment: @ansev, then in this example, the closest answer approximating 95% is 100% as its closer to 95% than 88%, but the important thing is that is should be the closest approximation derived from the analysis